# Observed Forbitten exception often in kibana dashboard

Tags: shell, docker, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm observing the below error message often in kibana. If I restarted the images and it looks fine for while but I'm loosing all my data as I explained in this below link.

[The data is getting lost whenever I restart the docker/elk image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316047/the-data-is-getting-lost-whenever-i-restart-the-docker-elk-image/58316289#58316289)

**Error Message:**

Erased the hostname in the snapshot.

[image]

I just searched and found that the below script will resolved that issue:

**Script:**

```
  PUT kindle_s_builds/_settings
     {
      "index": 
       {
        "blocks": 
        {
          "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
        }
       }
     }
```

**Output:**

```
  {
     "acknowledged" : true
  }
```

Kibana version : 6.6.0 and using docker/elk image to host the kibana dashboard.

But nothing helps. Can anyone let me know how can I resolve this issue? and what is the root cause and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your ES cluster has gone into read-only mode due to very less disk space.

Can you check if your ES cluster is having sufficient disk space? You can run this curl command

```
curl -u username:password -XGET "http://ES_HOST:9200/_cat/allocation?v&pretty"
```

to know about the free disk space in your cluster.

Also, have a look at [Elasticsearch error: cluster_block_exception [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)], flood stage disk watermark exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609417/elasticsearch-error-cluster-block-exception-forbidden-12-index-read-only-all)

Answer (score 0):

There are two angles to your problem:

1. The indexes are becoming read only and allow delete because you ran out of disk and as a way to warn you elastic did that. You already found the solution which is to set read_only_allow_delete as false on affected indexes.
2. You are losing your data because whenever the container is destroyed and created again the history is lost. You need to mount a physical disk folder inside your container. You can use the `-v` option in the docker run command as below:

```
docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200  -p 5044:5044 -v /Users/mk/data:/var/lib/elasticsearch --name elk sebp/elk
```

This will serve as a persistent storage for your data and every time the container is destroyed, the data will be safe on disk.